# Dash's "search your computer and online sources" stops working after a while

Tags: unity, unity-dash

The dash "search your computer and online sources" just spins and hang. It works a few times after each reboot, but then simply stops working. If I select files or applications the dash search works, but the default one "search your computer and online sources" hangs with a spinning wheel. It's been like that since 12.04 I think. 14.04 now and same problem.

I have only apps and files selected under categories and sources.

Any idea what's wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Excluding online search results when searching in Dash could help.

System Settings -> Security & Privacy -> Include online search results

http://www.unixmen.com/disable-unity-online-search-feature-ubuntu-14-10/

Answer (score 0):

I'm running version 14.04LTS on a Dell D630 with 4Gb of RAM.

I was having a related problem like this.  When I pressed on the Ubuntu icon to "Search your computer and online sources", I was presented with a pink hued screen and much pixelation.  Sometimes it even locked up the computer.  What I did was go to "Settings -> Security & Privacy", then click on "Files & Applications".  Turn off 'Record File and application usage", and press "Clear usage data...".  After this the search your computer... returned to normal.  I'm guessing of course, but something it was trying to display was not compatible with my display.  Clearing out the search data fixed it.  (for now)

Comment: This is an answer to a different problem.